# How to find whether two years of time series data are statistically significantly different from each other

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, python, pandas

I have several years of time series data with data points (# of cars) taken every 5 minutes (have filled in any missing data points). Wondering the best way to check whether there is a statistical difference between two different years of time series data from this data set, ie 2019 data vs 2020 data (expecting there should be a difference due to covid). Would you just t test the mean # of cars of each year, or is there something more specific? Any tests available in python are especially appreciated since I am using that for my code